# installing mongrel2 on precise pangolin?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mongrel2

Might be a dumb question, but is there a ppa or easy way to install mongrel2 on precise pangolin using the package manager? If installing from source is the current best way, that would be fine too, but I'd prefer keeping everything up to date via apt-get...

Answer (score 4):

be warned, there's a little bug that stops the sample app working with -sudo. The chroot jail doesn't include /proc, which pgm needs to be there to check capabilities, and because libzmq has been compiled with --enable-pgm, even if you weren't planning on using pgm you'll hit a trap divide error (just check dmesg).

this is all a long way of saying you should change to the directory you're running mongrel2 in and do this:

$ mkdir -p proc && sudo mount --bind /proc proc

that way, pgm can see /proc, and everything is happy.

(sourced from https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/issues/78 )

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the tarball.
mongrel2 relies on the zeromq package and you *can* install that via apt-get:

```
apt-get install libzmq-dev
```

It is however not so difficult to make a compiling tar in a .deb file and put it in a private apt repository (i.e. not a mirror of your distribution, just something with .deb files you generated). 
I find the overhead for testing local patches a bit too much, but when I had to distribute the results of that to multiple computers I used that. You might want to look at http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286